# How can i pass/detect a button click event from a new form in form1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the new form:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsUrl = TextBoxURL.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsFilename = TextBoxFilename.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsSaveto = TextBoxBrowse.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

In Form1

```
private void btnAddNewDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNewDownloads addnew = new AddNewDownloads();
            addnew.Show();
        }
```

Now i want that when i click on the btnOK button in the new form to get all the Properties.Settings.Default in form1. Do i need somehow to make btnOK click event also in form1 ? I want that only when i click btnOK and after it's saving the settings then in form1 to get this settings. The problem is i don't know in form1 when i clicked btnOK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code which raises an event in Form1 when `btnOK` is clicked on `AddNewDownloads` form. Hence your problem is resolved as `Form1` knows when `btnOK` is clicked. I have used Notepad to write the code, so try below code and let me know if it works. I will revisit the code in Visual Studio.

```
//--------------Form1 code

//declaring addnew object as class level or Method level depends on your design
//I prefer declaring class level as we can access addnew object properties
//from anywhere in Form1
AddNewDownloads addnew;

private void btnAddNewDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (addnew == null)
    {
        addnew = new AddNewDownloads();
        addnew.BtnOkClicked += addnew_BtnOkClicked;
    }

    addnew.Show();
}

private void addnew_BtnOkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //place your code here to 
    MessageBox.Show("Event raised by Ok button in AddNewDownloads");

}



//----------------------AddNewDownloads code
//declare a class level event
public event EventHandler BtnOkClicked;

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This will fire an event to be caught by subscriber
    //which is Form1.. put a break point in 
    OnGotClosed(EventArgs.Empty);

    //I am not sure where yo want to put Properties.Settings
    //So removed it from here... but you can decide and put 
    //as per your design
}

protected virtual void OnBtnOkClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = BtnOkClicked;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. On `AddNewDownloads` form select form properties and assign `btnOK` to [`AcceptButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) property. That will assign `DialogResult.OK` to form's [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property when you click button.
2. Use [`addnew.ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of simple `Show()`.
3. Verify return value of `ShowDialog()` call.

Code for Form1:

```
private void btnAddNewDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var addnew = new AddNewDownloads())
    {
       if (addnew.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
          return;

       // get settings here
    }
}
```

Comment: I did all changes and when i click to show the new form btnAddNewDownload_Click it's getting to the using...and open/show the new form. But then when i click on the OK button it's not getting again to the btnAddNewDownload_Click event.

Comment: If i add in the addNewDownload_Click event inside the using...the line addnew.btnOK.Click += BtnOK_Click; then in the event i'm doing: private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.AddNewDownloadsUrl);
        } then it's working.